# Cannot cast scalar from dtype('<U1') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'

Tags: python, pytorch

When I run the 'StyleGAN2' in colab, I faced this question:
Cannot cast scalar from dtype('<U1') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'

I searched for a long time, but I still don't know how to solve it.
I tried some ways. But it didn't work.

The full code(just a part of StyleGan2):

```
network = '\uC18C\uB140\uC758\uC138\uACC4'
network_pkl = '/content/network/' + meta_data[network][0] + '.pkl'

print('Loading networks from "%s"...' % network_pkl)
device = torch.device('cuda')
with dnnlib.util.open_url(network_pkl) as f:
    G = legacy.load_network_pkl(f)['G_ema'].to(device) # type: ignore

#@markdown **2) Seed**
#@markdown Use -1 for random seed or type a specific seed (from 0 up to 2^32-1):

seeds =  -1#@param {type: "number"}
if seeds == -1:
    seeds = np.random.randint(2**32 - 1, size=1)
else:
    seeds = [seeds]
print('Seed : ', seeds)

#@markdown **3) Truncation**
truncation_psi = 0 #@param {type:"slider", min:0, max:1, step:0.05}

#@markdown **4) noise**
noise_mode = 'random' #@param ['const', 'random', 'none']

# Labels
label = torch.zeros([1, G.c_dim], device=device)
if G.c_dim != 0:
    label[:, class_idx] = 1

#@markdown **Generate images**
def generate_images(seeds_ = seeds,
                    latent_vector = None,
                    truncation_psi_ = truncation_psi,
                    noise_mode_ = noise_mode,
                    class_idx = label,
                    network = network_pkl): 
  imgs=[]
  with dnnlib.util.open_url(network) as f:
    G = legacy.load_network_pkl(f)['G_ema'].to(device) # type: ignore

  if latent_vector == None : 
    for seed_idx, seed in enumerate(seeds_):
        # print('Generating image for seed %d (%d/%d) ...' % (seed, seed_idx, len(seeds)))
        z = torch.from_numpy(np.random.RandomState(seed).randn(1, G.z_dim)).to(device)
        img = G(z, class_idx, truncation_psi=truncation_psi_, noise_mode=noise_mode_)
        img = (img.permute(0, 2, 3, 1) * 127.5 + 128).clamp(0, 255).to(torch.uint8)        
        imgs.append(PIL.Image.fromarray(img[0].cpu().numpy(), 'RGB'))
  else:
    for i in range(len(latent_vector)):     
        img = G(latent_vector[i], class_idx, truncation_psi=truncation_psi_, noise_mode=noise_mode_)
        img = (img.permute(0, 2, 3, 1) * 127.5 + 128).clamp(0, 255).to(torch.uint8)       
        imgs.append(PIL.Image.fromarray(img[0].cpu().numpy(), 'RGB'))

  return imgs

image = generate_images('/content/input/liang.jpg')
image[0].save('/content/results/generate_image.png')
display(Image(filename='/content/results/generate_image.png'))
```

Complete Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
_mt19937.pyx in numpy.random._mt19937.MT19937._legacy_seeding()

TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-aa5c6201c6e0> in <module>()
     86   return imgs
     87 
---> 88 image = generate_images('/content/input/liang.jpg')
     89 image[0].save('/content/results/generate_image.png')
     90 display(Image(filename='/content/results/generate_image.png'))

<ipython-input-26-aa5c6201c6e0> in generate_images(seeds_, latent_vector, truncation_psi_, noise_mode_, class_idx, network)
     71         # print('Generating image for seed %d (%d/%d) ...' % (seed, seed_idx, len(seeds)))
     72         # numpy.array(wavelength,dtype='float64')
---> 73         z = torch.from_numpy(np.random.RandomState(seed).randn(1, G.z_dim)).to(device)
     74         img = G(z, class_idx, truncation_psi=truncation_psi_, noise_mode=noise_mode_)
     75         img = (img.permute(0, 2, 3, 1) * 127.5 + 128).clamp(0, 255).to(torch.uint8)

mtrand.pyx in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.__init__()
_mt19937.pyx in numpy.random._mt19937.MT19937._legacy_seeding()
_mt19937.pyx in numpy.random._mt19937.MT19937._legacy_seeding()
TypeError: Cannot cast scalar from dtype('<U1') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'
```

Thank you very much !!!Please!!!!!

Comment: Looks like `seed` is a string, not an integer. Check if that's the case.

Comment: Thank you! I tried this way, but I still can't solve this problem :(

Comment: I suggest you print `seed` just before the call to `RandomState`.